# Problems recognizing var

Tags: c#, asp.net

So I've been working locally on my machine, trying to parse an XML document. Here's my code:

```
XDocument xmlInput = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(xml));
var properties = from p in xmlInput.Descendants("Property")
                     select new
                     {
                         PropertyID = Int32.Parse(p.Value)
                     };
```

This works fine locally. But when I push to the production server, I get this error when I'm setting `properties`:

> CS1002: ; expected

I think it's having a problem recognizing var, but I'm not completely sure. I think there might be some differences between my machine and the production server, but I don't know what. Is there maybe a specific namespace I should be looking for on my production server?

Comment: Perhaps an old version of .NET Framework on your server / application-pool? Check the bottom of the error message if it's a web application for version information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version of .net you are running on the server doesn't match your local version.

Basically, you need to install the .net 3.5 framework on your server.

Answer (score 2):

I assume this in a code behind file.  Be sure the site is running the same version of .Net in production as you are locally.

Answer (score 1):

First check you installed correct .Net Framework on your server (in this case at least 3.5) after that go to application pool of your web server and set default .net framework to latest one. may be you installed .net framework but by default in application pool it will be set to .net 2 and should change it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the default language setting in IIS manager on your production server. It should be set to the same as your local machine (C#) but it may be set to VB right now.